# "invoke-rc.d: initscript cups, action "start" failed." while configure cups

Tags: apt, dpkg

When I run `apt-get -f install`, I get the following abnormal output:

```
Setting up cups (1.5.0-8) ...
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript cups, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing cups (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 cups
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I'm running under **Ubuntu Oneiric Ocelot, x64**.
I'm not sure where to start to debug this.
I appreciate any suggestions any of you may have.

Comment: Sounds like cups failed to start for some reason. When you try to start it manually, what happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something is wrong with the configuration of [CUPS](http://www.cups.org) (network printing infrastructure for Linux).  If CUPS is not the problem you're trying to fix, you can work around it for now by removing CUPS (`apt-get remove cups`), and then re-trying the `apt-get -f install`.

If you're interested in diagnosing the CUPS problem, you can try a couple things to figure out what's going on.  `apt-get` is effectively running `start cups` (older Ubuntu and other distros would be running `/etc/init.d/cups start` or `service cups start`).  You can run that manually to see if it says anything useful (probably not).  Check for recently changed logs (`ls -ltra /var/log`) and see if any of them provide hints (often daemon programs like CUPS will write any error or warnings to a log file).

Also, check the [cups configuration file](http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/doc-1.5/ref-cupsd-conf.html) `/etc/cups/cupsd.conf` and see if anything looks incorrect.

Presumably this didn't happen out of the blue, though.  What was going wrong that inspired you to run `apt-get -f install` in the first place?

Comment: Ubuntu is now using [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) instead of SysV-like init scripts, so the command to run is `start cups` and the config file to look for problems is `/etc/init/cups`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  I've updated the answer to include these details.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear: `/etc/init/cups` is the _upstart_ configuration file that controls cups startup; the configuration file for CUPS itself is still `/etc/cups/cupsd.conf`.

Comment: Hm. I removed cups and then re-ran `apt-get -f install`, and it didn't even try to install cups over again. I would be lying if I said that I understood why I uninstalled a broken dependency and now it is no longer a dependency.

Comment: To answer your question (from your answer): I needed to install a package which uses cups. It, assumedly, failed on the same script, but I never saw this output because the terminal was closed by someone else when I was away from the computer. I was getting some very broken behavior and hoped that resolving dependencies and then reinstalling the mentioned package may fix this.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is, upstart can't start cups daemon. I have seen this problem since Sept. I hoped the stable release solve this bug.

I'm lazy and I didn't solve it, but I did small workaround (*only for desktops* with local printers):

```
mv /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.cupsd /etc/apparmor.d/bad_profiles/
# apparmor complains about cups profile

rm -f /etc/init.d/cups
# this is link to upstart-job
```

and I use init script (/etc/init.d/cups) like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# PATH should only include /usr/* if it runs after the mountnfs.sh script
PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
DESC="Common Unix Printing Daemon"
NAME=cupsd
DAEMON=/usr/sbin/$NAME
DAEMON_ARGS=""
PIDFILE=/var/run/cups/$NAME.pid
#SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/$NAME
SCRIPTNAME=./$NAME

# Exit if the package is not installed
[ -x "$DAEMON" ] || exit 0

# Read configuration variable file if it is present
[ -r /etc/default/$NAME ] && . /etc/default/$NAME

# Load the VERBOSE setting and other rcS variables
. /lib/init/vars.sh

# Define LSB log_* functions.
# Depend on lsb-base (>= 3.2-14) to ensure that this file is present
# and status_of_proc is working.
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

do_start()
{
        # Return
        #   0 if daemon has been started
        #   1 if daemon was already running
        #   2 if daemon could not be started
        start-stop-daemon --start --verbose --user lp --group lpadmin --pid $PIDFILE \
                --exec $DAEMON --test || return 1
        start-stop-daemon --start --verbose --user lp --group lpadmin --pidfile $PIDFILE \
                --exec $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_ARGS || return 2
        # Add code here, if necessary, that waits for the process to be ready
        # to handle requests from services started subsequently which depend
        # on this one.  As a last resort, sleep for some time.
        #$DAEMON $DAEMON_ARGS &
        #echo `pidof cupsd`>$PIDFILE
}

do_stop()
{
        # Return
        #   0 if daemon has been stopped
        #   1 if daemon was already stopped
        #   2 if daemon could not be stopped
        #   other if a failure occurred
        start-stop-daemon --stop --retry=TERM/30/KILL/5 --pidfile $PIDFILE --name $NAME
        RETVAL="$?"
        [ "$RETVAL" = 2 ] && return 2
        # Wait for children to finish too if this is a daemon that forks
        # and if the daemon is only ever run from this initscript.
        # If the above conditions are not satisfied then add some other code
        # that waits for the process to drop all resources that could be
        # needed by services started subsequently.  A last resort is to
        # sleep for some time.
        start-stop-daemon --stop --oknodo --retry=0/30/KILL/5 --exec $DAEMON
        [ "$?" = 2 ] && return 2
        # Many daemons don't delete their pidfiles when they exit.
        rm -f $PIDFILE
        return "$RETVAL"
}

do_reload() {
        #
        # If the daemon can reload its configuration without
        # restarting (for example, when it is sent a SIGHUP),
        # then implement that here.
        #
        start-stop-daemon --stop --signal 1 --verbose --pidfile $PIDFILE --name $NAME
        return 0
}

case "$1" in
  start)
        [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_daemon_msg "Starting $DESC" "$NAME"
        do_start
        case "$?" in
                0|1) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 0 ;;
                2) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1 ;;
        esac
        ;;
  stop)
      [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_daemon_msg "Stopping $DESC" "$NAME"
        do_stop
        case "$?" in
                0|1) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 0 ;;
                2) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1 ;;
        esac
        ;;
  status)
       status_of_proc "$DAEMON" "$NAME" && exit 0 || exit $?
       ;;
  #reload|force-reload)
        #
        # If do_reload() is not implemented then leave this commented out
        # and leave 'force-reload' as an alias for 'restart'.
        #
        #log_daemon_msg "Reloading $DESC" "$NAME"
        #do_reload
        #log_end_msg $?
        #;;
  restart|force-reload)
        #
        # If the "reload" option is implemented then remove the
        # 'force-reload' alias
        #
        log_daemon_msg "Restarting $DESC" "$NAME"
        do_stop
        case "$?" in
          0|1)
                do_start
                case "$?" in
                        0) log_end_msg 0 ;;
                        1) log_end_msg 1 ;; # Old process is still running
                        *) log_end_msg 1 ;; # Failed to start
                esac
                ;;
          *)
                # Failed to stop
                log_end_msg 1
                ;;
        esac
        ;;
  *)
       echo "Usage: $SCRIPTNAME {start|stop|status|restart|force-reload}" >&2
        exit 3
        ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Next you can write (as root):

```
# apt-get install -f
```

And you have to have bash.

Comment: Please, do some research on how to properly format your answers.